# sending message from my website to a chrome extension "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist."

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension using js. I am sending message from myWebsite.com using send message function. In the background.js file i added an eventListener using chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener.

However, I am getting the error in the console:

"Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist."

my manifest.js file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 1,
  "name": "myname",
  "short_name": "myname",
  "description": "test",
  "author": "myname",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "22",
  "offline_enabled": false,
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon-16x16.png",
    "48": "icons/icon-48x48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon-128x128.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/icon-128x128.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
  },
  "externally_connectable": {
    "matches": [ "*://*.mywebsite.com/*"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "nativeMessaging",
    "tabs",
    "cookies",
    "*://*.mywebsite.com/"
  ]
}
```

My background.js file:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
   console.log(request);
})
```

My code in mywebsite(where key is the id of the extension):

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(key, obj, function (response) {
    deferred.resolve(response);
});
```

Comment: "key" seems a weird choice for the name - are you sure you're not using the "key" value specified in manifest.json of an installed extension? Anyway as you can see in the documentation a similar setup just works so the problem probably lies somewhere outside of what's currently specified in your question.

Comment: any ideas when and why does this error occur? @wOxxOm

Comment: The idea is that there's something else wrong, not the code inside the question. It could be even a bug in Chrome so it would make sense to try an older portable Chrome.

Comment: I just tried the extension on windows machine and it worked. I am developing it on mac

Comment: Why do you have `"manifest_version": 1`? That's most certainly wrong as the rest of your manifest's structure is version 2. See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion